# Kubernetes cluster pods as Jenkins Build Agents

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-kubernetes

I have installed `Kubernetes plugin - 1.23.3` in our Jenkins and able to execute shell commands on kubernetes pod(Dynamic Jenkins Slave). this is working with default `jnlp & jenkins/jnlp-slave:latest`

Suppose if I change the below "Name" & "Docker Image" section to use our private registry & image under

```
Manage Jenkins --> Configure System--> Cloud --> Pod Template --> Container Template

Name: sonatype
Docker image:sonatype:4546/ubuntu-16.04
```

It doesn’t uses our private docker image and even doesn't run the shell commands on the pod-containers. The idea is to perform `build + static analysis` using our own docker image on Kubernetes cluster pods as dynamic Jenkins Build Agents.

How to use our private docker registry images and execute them as Jenkins slave in kubernetes cluster? i have below scripted pipeline code. Stage-1 "SCM Code checkout" to K8S work-node is working, next 2nd stage build it is launching pod agent from `template Kubernetes Pod Template`. but if fails with `docker: not found`. it seems trying to pull our registry image in pod. From our worker-node system's code need to be mounted in dynamic Jenkins slave pods and perform the build and next stages. Any direction to achieve would be helpful.

```
node ("kubupods") { 
       stage('Code Compile') { 
          sh 'hostname'
        }
                
      stage('Code Analysis') {    
         sh 'hostname'
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins by default will pull image from dockerhub. in your case the image sonatype:4546/ubuntu-16.04 . In order for you to use private registry you need to provide the private registry and its credentials if you are building in the pipeline. You can either provide it on the UI or you can do it via code as well . Refer [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#custom-registry)

After that you also need to tell kubernetes YAML as well about the private registry.
For that you can refer [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/). This is essentially two steps
a) create a kubernetes secret
b) Tell your deployment about the secret using `imagepullsecret` field.

Make sure you refer to you image as
`<username or registry URL/<image_name>:<tag(maybe $BUILD_NUMBER)>`

=============== Edit 1 after question has been added with a new problem =====

Configure plugins to install packages using Jenkins.

1. Go to Manage Jenkins
2. Global Tools Configuration
3. Docker -> Fill name (eg: Docker-latest)
   [image]
   Check on install automatically and then add installer (Download from here).
4. Then save

If you have installed on your machine then update the PATH variable in Jenkins with the location of Docker.

[Reference for Jenkins File](https://www.magalix.com/blog/create-a-ci/cd-pipeline-with-kubernetes-and-jenkins)

Comment: Yes you are right jenkins by default pulling images from dockerhub. We have sonatype nexus as private registry. Credentials I have already defined in Jenkins GUI. But that i didn't call it in my scripted pipeline. I ll check this part. So to spin up dynamic Kubernetes pods as Jenkins agents also yml file needed?

Comment: Though I don't get the part pods as Jenkins agent , I believe to deploy anything as a pod in k8s you would need a YAML , Check this https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cd/

Comment: To pull an image from our private registry, `kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=https://nexus-server/nexus/ --docker-username=admin --docker-password=password --docker-email=user@company.com` but it shows `error: no matches for kind "Secret" in version "v1"` docker login to our private registry is successful.

Comment: The above secret command worked for me , also please accept the answer if  it has helped you.

Comment: Do i need to create empty `yml` file manually under `~/.docker/` before running above commands?

Comment: nope you don't need a yaml , for debugging check `kubectl get secret ` . If you follow the other approach of using docker file , the file should be present in the system you need not create it.

Comment: Okay, i want to follow above command method. `kubectl get secret` returns `error: the server doesn't have a resource type "secret"` i  tried running above command on my worker server.

Comment: are you on cloud or on prem , plausible reasons for above is your kubernetes certificate expiry or your kubeconfig is cached. Lets continue on chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218209/kubernetes

Comment: above is solved by placing missing kubeconfig in the system where the command was executed

Answer (score 0):

Tarun's answer above assumes that you are building the image in the pipeline.

I do something similar in our pipeline, but we build a custom jnlp-slave image (loaded with the tools we need for CI/CD) outside of the pipeline and refer it in the kubernetes plugin yaml.

Build the custom jnlp-slave image. (Dockerfile below)

```
FROM jenkins/jnlp-slave:latest

# Download/install tools

ENTRYPOINT ["jenkins-slave"]
```

Push the custom jnlp-slave image to your private registry

```
docker build -t my-private-registry/jnlp-slave:custom .
docker push my-private-registry/jnlp-slave:custom
```

Define your Jenkinsfile so that the pod uses your image you built in the previous step.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  label:
    jenkins: slave
spec:
  containers:
  - name: jnlp
    image: my-private-registry/jnlp-slave:custom
}}}

stages {
  stage("Test") {
    sh("hostname")
  }
}
```

Our registry doesn't require authentication, but if it does, you'll need to provide the secret (as Tarun has mentioned) to the jenkins to let it authenticate into your registry.

Comment: @Mandopalooza, Thanks a lot for the answer. With this `https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin` instructions able to configure K8s Jenkins plugin through pipeline.